# Getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, parsing, syntax, backup

Minor problem with following code:

```
<?php  echo exec(‘cd /home/username/backup/files; tar -cvpzf `date +%y-%m-%d_%H-%M`.tar /home/username/public_html’); ?>
```

Error I am getting is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 1
```

Code above is line 1, would be nice to find a solution.

Thanks in advance for time and effort.

Comment: What's with those weird apostrophes?

Comment: Is this literally your code, with curly `‘` apostrophes?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: The curly `‘` replaced with `'` (single) and now it is running my backup (after it got a cronjob in Cpanel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotation marks around the command string are wrong.

Comment: It is because he copied and pasted. They are probably not the actual comma ASCII which is in his file.

Comment: I think it is because he copied and pasted something *to* his file, and thus the commas *are* in his file.

Comment: The  curly `‘` apostrophes where indeed wrong no clue how they came inside there. Corrected them with the `'` and it runs as. Too late for me and needing glasses.  
Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score -1):

Right after files;

```
/home/username/backup/files;
```

You should not have the ; after the files.

Comment: It's inside a quoted string that is being passed to the shell.